# Помогите разобраться с jQuery плагином int-tel-input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт с контактной формой, где есть поле ввода для телефона.

Моя задача - сделать так, чтобы в это поле ввода автоматически подтягивался международный телефонный код. Я решил реализовать задачу с помощью плагина [int-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)

Фронтенд получился - код отображается, нужный код устанавливается по IP.

Моих знаний не хватает на бэкэнд. После добавления плагина, поле ввода поделилось на 2 части - отдельно выпадающий список и отдельно поле для ввода цифр.

И, соответственно, на почту мне приходят данные только с цифрами, а информации по коду и стране нет.

Я не прошу готового решения, объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает и в какую сторону копать.

P.S. Задача усложняется еще и тем, что сайт сделан на конструкторе Platforma LP, и я не могу влезть в код или настраивать их форму.

```html
<div class="field" data-type="phone" style="width: 247px;">
  <div class="input">
    <div class="intl-tel-input allow-dropdown">
      <div class="flag-container">
        <div class="selected-flag" role="combobox" aria-owns="country-listbox" tabindex="0" title="Bhutan (འབྲུག): +975">
          <div class="iti-flag bt"></div>
          <div class="iti-arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="country-list hide" id="country-listbox" aria-expanded="false" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="iti-item-bt">
          <li class="country preferred" id="iti-item-us" role="option" data-dial-code="1" data-country-code="us">
            <div class="flag-box">
              <div class="iti-flag us"></div>
            </div><span class="country-name">United States</span><span class="dial-code">+1</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div><input class="form-control text" type="text" data-placeholder="true" value="" style="border-radius: 15px;" autocomplete="off" placeholder="17 12 34 56"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/js/intlTelInput-jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/14.0.6/js/utils.js"></script>
<script>
        $("[data-type='text'] .input .form-control, [data-type='phone'] .input .form-control").intlTelInput({
           allowDropdown: true,
           autoPlaceholder: "aggressive",
           initialCountry: "auto",
  geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
      var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
      success(countryCode);
    });
  },
});
    </script>
```

Comment: данные которые для отправки должны быть в инпутах с атрибутами name а у вас я вижу 1 инпут. Но не факт что если вы создадите инпуты, то они успешно отправятся. Или как вариант посмотреть куда отправляются данные оп сабмиту, перехватить событие, сконкатенировать код страны и прочие нужные данные, а после отправить их

Comment: на самом деле в конструкторе Platforma LP вы можете влезть в форму и выполнить любой js. Говорю вам это как разработчик, который участвовал в разработке этой платформы.

Comment: @stepankasyanenko выполнить JS код - да, это возможно. А вот задать элементу id нельзя

Comment: Если вы можете выполнить JS код, то в этом JS коде можете задать id элементу.